# How to to rename a folder in a Angular 6 project

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 6 project which I want to rename a folder in the project components. Is there a specific way to do this so I don't break anything? or am I over thinking this and its just a matter of renaming the folder? I am using Visual Studio Code as my IDE.

Comment: VSCode should ask you if you want to update all the files including the name of the file. Otherwise, you can use a global search (Ctrl + Shift + F) to find the previous name, and global replace  (Ctrl + Shift + H) to replace it.

Comment: You also have the [Move TS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stringham.move-ts) plugin which is very helpful for this kind of needs !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can go ahead and rename the folder and the only impact that you might have is during `import` of the components (Unless you decide to change the component names too)

for example in:

```
 import {XComponent} from '../foo/x.component';

 // refactor it to 
 import {XComponent} from '../bar/x.component';
```

You always global search the previous names of the folder from your IDE and replace it.